# Setting CNN input dimensions correctly (Pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robbymoseley/Desktop/IOP/IOP-ML/Model/IOP_model.py", line 201, in <module>
    logps = model(images)
  File "/Applications/Python Virtual Environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/robbymoseley/Desktop/IOP/IOP-ML/Model/IOP_model.py", line 95, in forward
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
  File "/Applications/Python Virtual Environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Python Virtual Environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 399, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/Applications/Python Virtual Environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 396, in _conv_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [6, 1, 5, 5], but got 2-dimensional input of size [10, 307200] instead
```

This is the model I am trying to use:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        # we use the maxpool multiple times, but define it once
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # in_channels = 6 because self.conv1 output 6 channel
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        # 5*5 comes from the dimension of the last convnet layer
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0])
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[0], hidden_sizes[1])
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[1], output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)  # no activation on final layer
        return x
```

Input images are 640x480.

Here is my main function as well:

```
if __name__ == __main__:

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")

    model = Net().to(device)

    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
    # images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
    print(images.shape)
    images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
    logps = model(images)
    loss = criterion(logps, labels)  # calculate the NLL loss

    # training process
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.003, momentum=0.9)

    loss_fn = nn.NLLLoss()

    # train the model
    train_model(num_epochs, model)

    # validate the model
    validate_model(model)

    print("Execution has finished")
```

How can I adjust either the expected input dimensions or the weights? Or can I change the dimensions of my input to properly reflect the structure of my model? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you print the shapes of your inputs and shapes after every step in your forward pass to debug it

Answer (score 0):

based off the convolutional part i did notice the problem, where your final pooling layer out channel was not calculated correctly

The following is how the code should work based off your input size that you mentioned 640x480x1

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        # we use the maxpool multiple times, but define it once
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # in_channels = 6 because self.conv1 output 6 channel
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        # 5*5 comes from the dimension of the last convnet layer
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 157 * 117, 256) # You didnt provide the numbers here but i did calculate the in channels based off the prev layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        print('Conv1 Shape: {}'.format(x.shape))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(x))
        print('Pool1 Shape: {}'.format(x.shape))
        x = self.conv2(x)
        print('Conv2 Shape: {}'.format(x.shape))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(x))
        print('Pool2 Shape: {}'.format(x.shape))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 157 * 117)
        print('Flatten Shape: {}'.format(x.shape))
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)  # no activation on final layer
        return x
    
model = Model()

model(torch.randn(1, 1, 640, 480)) # 1 Channel since your first conv layer input inchannel is 1
```

Output shape for each layer

```
model(torch.randn(1, 1, 640, 480))
Conv1 Shape: torch.Size([1, 6, 636, 476])
Pool1 Shape: torch.Size([1, 6, 318, 238])
Conv2 Shape: torch.Size([1, 16, 314, 234])
Pool2 Shape: torch.Size([1, 16, 157, 117])
Flatten Shape: torch.Size([1, 293904])
```